# Changing the default length unit in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, lengths, coordinates

Is there a way to change the default length unit in tikz to the ex unit? I have trouble while calculating complicated coordinates in tikz when I'm using the ex unit (I always get an error or a wrong result). However, as soon as I get rid of the length unit, I do more complicated computations with parenthesis involved and won't get any errors. I thought maybe if I can set ex to be the default length unit and drop it in the syntax, I can still work with this unit and won't run into the errors.

Comment: Try `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex, y=1ex]`... (but the computations errors could be another problem, so think about preparing an MWE and asking in another question...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [set the `x` and `y` vectors](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.2):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex, y=1ex]
    \draw[ultra thick, cyan] (0,0) -- (1cm,1cm);
    \draw[thick, red] (0,0) -- (1ex,1ex);
    \draw[thin, black] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But notice that the `ex` unit is font-dependent, so it will change with the font in use *outside* the `tikzpicture` (which is probably what you want, but...)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it. Yes, indeed it is the reason I like ex unit. Because if I decide to change my font at some point, I don't need to scale all my tikz pictures one by one.